# How to return just the value of two numbers being added?

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick

I am working on a cart page and would like to add two values: the # of products (static) + the state quantity (+ or - 1 depending on onClick). For example, I am getting a result like this "20+1" and when I click (+) it will become "20+2". How would I get the result to read just 22?

My code is this. props.ProductData.price is static and stata.quantity is increasing by 1 or -1:

```
<span className="quantity">{props.productData.price}+{state.quantity}</span>
```

Would I have to write a function? If so, could you help set it up? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

addition and subtraction are code, not text to be displayed, so react needs to be told to treat as code. try:`<span className="quantity">{props.productData.price + state.quantity}</span>`

Comment: Hmm... that's giving me the numbers added like this: 20+1 = 201.

Comment: <span className="quantity">{(props.productData.price/props.productData.price)*props.productData.price + state.quantity}</span>
This is giving me 20+1=21. Which is doing the addition. Now, I guess my problem is how to have it start at 20 and not do the addition upon the first rendering

Comment: I got it figured out. Thank you very much for your help Hillel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function addition :

```
addition = (nb1, nb2) => return (nb1 + nb2);
...
<span>{addition(props.productData.price, state.quantity)}</span>
```